# Response.write to <head>

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Hopefully this won't be a difficult question for someone to answer, but I am having a lot of trouble finding the solution online. I am trying to add some HTML to my asp.net page from the code behind (It's VB.net). I would like to add the HTML into the head section of my page but  can only add to the body currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put code in the head, just like the body. For example:

```
<%= CallAMethodThatReturnsAStringOfHtml() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a property in your code behind and add your html in the Page_Load method:

```
Public MyHtml As String
```

then in the head section of your HTML just use the literal notation:

```
<%= MyHtml %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have `runat` attribute on your head element and you will be able to access it

```
<head id="someHead" runat="server">

</head>
```

Now in your codebehind, you can set it like

```
 someHead.InnerHtml="<script src='somelibrary.js' ></script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this way, and it worked:

on the .aspx file:

...
    
        <% 
            Response.Write(GetDisclosureText()); 
        %>
    
...

on the aspx.cs file:

```
    protected string GetDisclosureText()
    {
        string disclosure = ""; 
        // ...Apply  custom logic ...
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(disclosure))
        {
            return disclosure;
        }
        return "Error getting Disclosure Text";
    }
```

Note the only difference is that I call Response.Write, not just the function.